# redshift/Postgresql 8.0 revoke connect to database of a user

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

How can I revoke access to a database for a user?

I tried
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE dev FROM public_readonly;
and still I can connect.

Looks like by default all users can connect to all databases.

Note that this is a Redshift question so solution with pgpass changes will obviously not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably talking about a [superuser account](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_superusers.html):

> The masteruser, which is the user you created when you launched the cluster, is a superuser.

And

> A database superuser bypasses all permission checks. Be very careful when using a superuser role. We recommend that you do most of your work as a role that is not a superuser. Superusers retain all privileges regardless of GRANT and REVOKE commands.

That is probably the reason why you can still connect.

To create less powerful users use normal [CREATE USER](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_USER.html) statement, then all permissions should work as expected.